# How can I log shutdown messages?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, shutdown, logging

I'm trying to log the shutdown messages in my linux, I see "Asking all remaining processes to terminate..." and then there is a big delay, and then there is some other chatter and log messages which whizz past too quickly to read before the machine shutdown.

Here's what I've tried:

`sudo find /var/log -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sudo zgrep "all remaining process"`

But the message I see isn't anywhere there.  Is that stuff logged anywhere?  If not, is there a way to log it?

I'm on Ubuntu 13.10.

Comment: Back in the 1990s, we still had an archaic (even then) hard-copy style terminal hooked up as our console device, which did address this problem nicely. But it's not likely an answer you can use. I suppose with the changes in what is NOW "available and cheap" you could probably point a videocamera (perhaps in high-speed/slow-motion mode) at the console screen...

Comment: I want a solution where I can copy-paste the plaintext, rather than extract it from an image.